# VSCode: hiding some default menu items

Tags: visual-studio-code

Simple question: is there a way to hide some default menu items in VSCode? For instance, I would like to hide the *Zoom In*, *Zoom Out* and *Reset Zoom* items in the *View* menu.

The problem is that I have a laptop with a HiDPI screen: 13 inch, 1920x1080. On this screen, the *View* menu does not fit completely and looks ugly (see screenshot). I am a recent convert to VSCode, love the Command Palette but would still like to browse the menus occasionally.

I have tried searching on Stack Overflow and googling but cannot seem to find anything related.

[image: ugly View mernu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as of VS Code 1.21.

[This feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9285) tracks something similar for context menus. Not sure if we have an issue tracking this for menu bar items