# How to add a new menu item to the File menu in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to create an add a custom menu to the main menu bar (preferably the File menu) in Visual Studio with an extension? I want to add a new project type.

Related question as this but for Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio: 
[Adding a Menu to the Visual Studio Menu Bar within an Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987295/adding-a-menu-to-the-visual-studio-menu-bar-within-an-add-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for the same thing, but currently, I don't think it's possible. [This link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) describes how an extension can create menu items, but the only "contribution points" are in context menus.  There is no contribution point for the top-level File menu.  I have also been unsuccessful finding a configuration file for editing the existing menus.

Additionally, this other SO post seems to confirm this: [VSCode: hiding some default menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053829/vscode-hiding-some-default-menu-items)

opened https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74013

Comment: I see you added a feature request! :) right on. I was adding one at the same time https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74014 lol. Let me know and if it's the same I'll close mine.

Comment: I would say your request is slightly different, and more specific.  It would probably be a different contribution point.  I think leave both requests and let the VSCode team decide to merge/dupe them if they want.

Comment: Re your feature request: I agree with your 20 May post that your request is different from 74014.  I came here hoping there might be a way for me to add cmds to the menu (like there is in jEdit).  Not a cmd from an extension (which I think is what 74014 is), just an ordinary built-in cmd.  But The Powers That Be decided your request duplicates some other request, *without saying what that other request is*, and then locked the request so no one could comment.  What a pain; not what I would call friendly.

Comment: it's better to create the custom item in the action bar (left verticle bar) instead of creating it in the menu bar (top horizontal bar). after that, build your things by extending the sidebar panel. you can find more related to this at: code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview